# UINavigationBar blinks after pushing an UIViewController with hideBottomBarOnPush = YES

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an app target for ios7 that the rootViewController is an UITabBarController. The first tab has an UITableViewController within an UINavigationController. There is also a UIViewController to be presented after selecting one item from the TableView.

I'm using StoryBoard and I've added some static cells to the UITableView.

UIViewController has the option Hide Bottom Bar On Push selected.

[image: HideBottomBarOnPush selected]

When calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I push the UIViewController. Here is where the issue happens. The NavigationBar blinks in the right side. Also, when the view is popped, the NavigationBar blinks again.

If I deselect HideBottomBarOnPush option, the blink goes away.

I added a sample project on github [HideBottomBarOnPushExample](https://github.com/paventuri/HideBottomBarOnPushExample.git).

Any ideas on what is going on? Is there any workaround to that annoying blink?